# TFS 2017 Update1: Programmatically updating TFS Release Definitions removes server phase (manual intervention)

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

In TFS 2017 Update 1 after downloading programmatically a release definition with REST api, I edited the downloaded json and uploaded again programmatically.

The changes are present. However the server phase of manual intervention is missing in the environments after the changes.

Can someone else reproduce it?

The program C# to download and upload the release definition is at my github page [githubpage](https://github.com/BaskiGIT/TFS/blob/master/DownloadAndUploadTFSRMReleaseDefinition)

Comment: How did you judge the manual intervention is missing or not? Did you just not find the related task or the task is not working any more? You could give a try with this tutorial--[use manual Intervention (Task)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2016/09/18/how-to-use-manual-intervention-task-in-release-management/).

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT: The release definition has manual intervention phase. But after it is updated programmatically that phase is missing. After updating I could see that the phase is removed. Also in the history those steps are removed as well.

Comment: Not only that the server phase goes missing, but also any further agent/server phases defined after the first server phase.

Comment: Did you just mean if you create a new release definition now, the server phase is also missing? How about the old another release definition( without updating by you)?

Comment: Let me explain again. I have a release definition already created manually. I have 5 environments defined in it - Dev, Test, UAT, Prod, Stable. In each environment I have an agent phase with few tasks, followed by a server phase with manual intervention, then an agent phase with few more tasks. I has a C# program which downloads the release definition as json. I have added few variables in the  json and uploaded the json back using the C# program. After updating this way the new variables I have added are present. However the server phase and the agent phase below it are missing altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `api-version=3.2-preview.3` instead of `3.0-preview.2` when you update the release definition.

Comment: With TFS 2017 Update 1 RTM I see that the api-version available is 3.1-preview.3 and not 3.2-preview.3. I will try with 3.1-preview.3 and see how it goes..

Comment: With 3.1-preview.3 this is resolved. Marking your answer.