# Lost workflowtask (task group) after updated release definition

Tags: json, powershell, tfsbuild

I've release definition which has more than environment (QA, Stage...). Within environment, I've agent phase. Within agent phase, I've task group. Initially, the release definition is having trigger option (QA - auto, Stage - manual). What I've trying to do is:

1. Download release definition
2. Update release definition (just change the trigger option for Stage environment from manual to auto)
3. Import release definition.

After I downloaded, updated and import release definition, the agent phase name is automatically changed to the same name as environment, and the task group is lost. I went to history and do a diff, I see the agent phase name is changed and entire Workflowtask section is gone for all environment. I checked json file that I downloaded and updated, and it does have workflowtask section. Am I missing something or this is a bug? Below is my powershell script. Please advise.

```
$releaseuri = $tpcUri + "/" + $teamprojectname + "/_apis/Release/definitions/" + $releaseid # + "?api-version=4.0-preview.3"

Write-Host $releaseuri
$releasetemplate = $downloadlocation + "\" + $releasetemplatename
Write-Host $releasetemplate
# Get release definition and save to local computer
$Jsonfile = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseuri -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials
$Jsonfile | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File $releasetemplate

$ReleaseFile = "C:\DevOps\updatedmytest1.json"

#import release definition
$Uri = $tpcUri + "/" + $teamprojectname + "/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=3.0-preview.2"
Write-Verbose "URI: $uri"
Write-Host "Importing release definition........"
$release = gc $ReleaseFile -Raw -ea Stop
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $release
```

Best Regards,
Andy Pham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this part in your code:

`$Uri = $tpcUri + "/" + $teamprojectname + "/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=3.0-preview.2"`

Please use another version of your Rest API version  instead of `3.0-preview.2` . This issue should be the Rest API version you are using.

According to the [tutorials](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions#update-a-release-definition) in MSDN:

> **api-version**
>
> *Required. Version of the API to use. This should be set to '**4.0-preview.3**' to use this version of the API.*

Also take a look at this similar question:  [TFS 2017 Update1: Programmatically updating TFS Release Definitions removes server phase (manual intervention)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595575/tfs-2017-update1-programmatically-updating-tfs-release-definitions-removes-serv)